# What is this hash of array data structure called?

Tags: data-structures, arrays, hash-tables

I've created a data structure that is a hash of arrays with a special property: the hash keeps track of the combined order in which items are appended to its arrays.

For example (pseudocode):

```
h = HashOfArray()

h["a"].append(1) // accessing an unset key returns an empty array
h["b"].append(2)
h["a"].append(3)
h["b"].append(4)

h["a"]
>>> [1, 3]

h["b"]
>>> [2, 4]

h.items()
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm struggling with coming up with a good name for this data structure. Does it have a commonly used name? I've called it `HashOfArray` but that fails to convey its main property: that it maintains the combined append order of the arrays.

Example implementation in Ruby:
https://gist.github.com/kajic/7981533

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: Here is an implementation in Ruby: https://gist.github.com/kajic/7981533

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but it looks as though you just keep a `parent` array, and insert into in whenever you insert into a child...

Comment: The `parent` variable is a reference to the parent hash which contains the arrays. Every time an object is appended to any one of the hashes, a reference to the object is also appended to the items array on the parent. The items array therefore has the combined append order of the objects inserted into all the arrays.

Comment: If there is only one array then this is like python's *ordered dictionary*.

Comment: Yuval Filmus: It's similar to an ordered dictionary, except instead of keeping track of the order in which keys are inserted, it keeps track of the order in which objects are appended to the arrays stored at its keys.

Answer (score 1):

No, this data structure does not have a commonly-used name. It so similar to a  hash table that it is very unlikely to have been the subject of a peer-reviewed publication.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a name that will describe your entire data structure, but to simplify it you can name it: `HashQueue` as your arrays are Queue.